# Event of catching at least one fish on a given day

Tags: probability

So let E be the event that at least on fish is caught

F- event I travel to Location 1

G- event I travel to Location 2

H- event I travel to Location 3

P(F)= .25

P(G)= .35

P(H)= .4

P(E|F)= .85

P(E|G)= .65

P(E|H)= .2

Is P(E) as easy as .25*.85 + .35*.65 + .4*.2?
I am trying to find the probability that at least one fish is caught on a given day.

Comment: Yes, it is that easy.

Comment: You are traveling to exactly one of the three locations?  I ask because saying “at least one fish” suggests there’s some way you might catch more than one, e.g., if you traveled to two locations on the same day.